# Spring-datetimepicker always getting the same date value

Tags: spring, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am trying to send two date values as parameters to spring from a jsp page using datetimepicker.No matter which date I introduce in datetimepicker from my jsp page in spring controller I am always getting Sun Jan 01 16:36:00 EET 2017.The time is valid, but the date is always the first day of the current year.

```
 @InitBinder
 public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm");
     sdf.setLenient(true);
     binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(sdf, true));
 }
```

Script:

```
<script>$(function() {
    $(".datepicker-1").datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm',
    });
});</script>
```

I ve tried using dd/MM/yyyy in jsp code for datetimepicker and in the initBinder method but I am getting an error.